# How to convert .db .sqlite3 file to hash/json using Ruby/RubyOnRails

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, hash

Does anyone know of any way of reading/converting .db .sqlite3 file into hash, json, csv on the fly in ruby/rails?
I know I could openit with the sqlite3 gem or using pg, but ideally I want to do it on the fly without fiddling with the db connections. The file will be provided by the end user, so I want to open it (convert to something I can work on such as hash) and read bits of data I need from it, then map it and save to our db.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The end user will provide a file that is produced from a sqlite db? Is that correct? ISO csv you can do a sql dump and sql load. The file is sql and it's readable and editable. Would that meet your needs?

Comment: Rails would probably use a DB connection. It sounds like you want a command line tool to convert the DB. You can call the command line tool from Rails.

Comment: You would use the [dump command from the SQLite](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-dump/) command line tool to dump the data as a SQL file. Dumping it as JSON is actually a huge step down as its not typed and you need to jump through additional hoops serializing and unserializing the data. Backing up and or migrating databases is a fairly common task so you don't need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @LesNightingill thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, I am in no control of what is dumped into the file. The third party android apps are dumping those files into S3 bucket, then it is downloaded by the user and it has to be somehow processed. Currently, it is opened on PC using DBBRowser and processed manually. I need to automate this. I will fiddle with dumping sql as CSV, a bit more work but may just do, thanks.

Comment: @BSeven Unfortunately, request to use command line tool from rails was rejected. Thank you for your reply.